# How to find the list of my rejected edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I saw it before [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/163039/revisions), but now I can't. I checked meta SE and found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104579/260336). I was able to see my rejected edits in [Math SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/45755/my-rejected-edits) (I'm 140308) but not in [Stats SE/CV](http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/45755/my-rejected-edits) (I'm 44339 ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your user profile choose [All actions, then choose Suggestions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/44339/bclc?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Comment: Thanks whuber! ^-^